# How can one edit Illustrator CS .eps files on OSX?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, eps

In my free physics textbook on http://www.motionmountain.net , there are hundreds of images, all made with Illustrator CS 11 (yes, from around the year 2010) in eps format. But the new Illustrator has become unaffordable, even more so for a non-profit organisation. How can one edit such .eps files now?

My attempts in the last days (August 2017) gave these results:

- Corel Draw: does not seem to exist for OSX
- Xara Designer Pro: does not seem to exist for OSX
- Affinity Designer: has a trial version; but one cannot edit the text in the .eps files coming from Illustrator CS; font sizes are wrong.
- AutoCAD LT: the trial version cannot open .eps files
- Inkscape: able to edit text in .eps files, but saved .eps files garble the result and the font, wrong when imported back to Illustrator.
- McGimp: does not seem to be able to edit text from Illustrator .eps

What is the best way to proceed? Is this summary wrong in some cases? Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: I was pretty sure Inskcape should be able to do this – what did you try/where did that fail?

Comment: When you edit text, and save it again, it is garbled when opened again in Illustrator CS. And the fonts are wrong.

Comment: But it technically _works_. You can open the files and edit them. That there is a problems with fonts, that would be a separate issue (it might have to do with system fonts etc.). My point being: Inkscape really is the go-to non-Illustrator software.

Comment: You can subscribe to Illustrator for 1 month, then cancel the subscription. This is a cost of $30. Subscribe for 1 year up front and it's $20/month (~$240 total). In fact, you can download the (fully functional) *trial* of Illustrator and use it for a month free of charge. Non-profit organizations have money for critical business needs... If this is truly a need, the cost is minimal.

Comment: Where exactly can one download a free trial of Illustrator CS (not CC)?

Comment: The free trial of Illustrator CC will open Creative Suite version files as well as back-save to the same CS version if needed. The $30/mo is less than some people spend on coffee in a *week*. I really **detest** the subscription model. However, at some point  the realization sets in that you can spend 100+ hours trying to find a viable alternative, wasting money that way (time = money), or give in and subscribe. Unless you are running an OS which still supports CS6 and you can find a legal  version for sale. I'm NOT an advocate for the CC subscription. It's often a necessary evil though.

Comment: To be clear.. I believe Adobe should be investigated for anti-trust due to their near monopoly in the industry and essentially blackmailing customers into a position where they MUST subscribe if they want access to their original copyrighted intellectual property. But until (and if) that happens, there's often little choice but the subscription if you want to access older Adobe files.

Comment: If you still have the discs CS came on.. you can install that and still use it provided you are running an operating system which supports it. Since CS came with a *perpetual license*. Often a decent alternative is to buy an older Mac running an older version of OSX if you only need occasional access to files and still have the software. I keep an old G4 cube and an iBook around for this reason.

Comment: Indeed I have Illustrator CS on an old Mac, but it does not run on the new Mac :-(

Comment: "Newest" is NOT always "best". Just keep the old Mac around for when you need to edit the .ai files.

Comment: As far as Inkscape is concerned, have you tried perhaps saving as .svg from  Inkscape instead of .eps - and see if that works better for you in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

if you convert the fonts to paths in Inkscape before export all should be ok

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem you are having with Inkscape are misnamed fonts. Try the following:

1. Open EPS in Inkscape.
2. Select some text.
3. Look at the XML of that text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>).
4. There will be a font entry somewhere. Change this to a reasonable, installed font (usually the font you originally used). If this works, rejoice and continue. Otherwise despair.
5. Use some search-and-replace tool to change all similar font instructions in the SVG’s source.
6. If this does not fix all text, you probably used more than one font. Select a remaining broken text and go to step 3.